# How to find the files in the Linux Kernel which are used to handle the keyboard operations?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I already download the Linux Kernel v 4.12.7. I have to locate/find the files in Linux Kernel v 4.12.7 which are used to handle the keyboard operations.

Where these files are located and their names?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle the keyboard operations"? Please provide more details about what you are looking for and what you want to do with the files when you find them.

Comment: There's quite a few "keyboard operations" related files in the kernel (PS/2 keyboard drivers, hid layer, input layer, keyboard mapping layer), you really have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @BLayer I am looking for the name of files that handle the keyboard operaton/response. just to know about the that files. I am student and I want to know that files because I have to build a kernel for my project.

Answer (score 2):

The directory `linux/drivers/input/keyboard` contains driver source files for a number of keyboards. For example, `atkbd.c` contains the driver for the classic AT and PS/2 keyboards. The most popular keyboard type today, the USB keyboard, is handled in user space by the [libusb](http://libusb.info) library; only the low level USB drivers are in the kernel.

Comment: USB keyboards are usually HID keyboards and are not handled in userspace via libusb, but via the HID kernel drivers, as you can easily verify by looking at `dmesg` after plugging it in.